# Infinite loop with aws elb and varnish - apache redirect 301

Tags: apache, varnish, amazon-elb

We have varnish and apache in front of our AWS ELB and for each https redirect we are seeing "Infinite loops" error in the apache log -

```
[Sun Nov 10 03:06:36 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: https://www.*******.com/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.anaplan.com%
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix, we had to add this on our varnish configuration -

```
sub vcl_hash {
hash_data(req.url);
hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
return(hash);
}
```

Cheers,

Reigner S. Yrastorza